# reporting services: use a custom assembly with a local (RDLC) report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting

I am designing a report that will be used in local mode (an RDLC file) in a Winform app.  I have a custom assembly with a static class that has some functions that I want to use inside of the report (as expressions).

I have found all sorts of help for doing this with RDL reports, but I'm running into a permissions problem with my RDLC report.

I get the following error at runtime:
"The report references the code module (my module), which is not a trusted assembly".

I know that this is some kind of a code security issue, but I'm not sure what to do to fix it.  The documentation that I have seen online is aimed at RDL reports, and it instructs me to edit a SQL Server-specific policy file.  I'm using RDLC, so there is no sql server involved.  What do I need to do to acquire the appropriate permissions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [AddTrustedCodeModuleInCurrentAppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.addtrustedcodemoduleincurrentappdomain.aspx) method of the 
[ReportViewer.LocalReport Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.addtrustedcodemoduleincurrentappdomain.aspx) (reportViewer.LocalReport.AddTrustedCodeModuleInCurrentAppDomain("your assembly")).

Also make sure you use the [AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx) attribute with your assembly ([assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]).

Comment: That was the trick!  I had the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers, but I missed the call to AddTrustedCodeModuleInCurrentAppDomain.  Incidentally, that method has been deprecated for .Net 4.0, and there is a new method for doing it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The AddTrustedCodeModuleInCurrentAppDomain method is obsolete for .Net 4.0. Visual Studio 2010 disable the call of this method. But there is the [AddFullTrustModuleInSandboxAppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.addfulltrustmoduleinsandboxappdomain.aspx) method in the LocalReport property of ReportViewer class (reportViewer.LocalReport.AddFullTrustModuleInSandboxAppDomain(myAssemblyStrongName)). It requires the strong name of the assembly. My application executes fine from Visual Studio but I get the error "The report references the code module (my module), which is not a trusted assembly" when I'm manually run exe-file from folder "bin". What it can be?

Answer (score 2):

@StefanHa's comment provides the answer, in case that blog post disappears here's the code that worked for me:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Policy;
PermissionSet permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permissions.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
permissions.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
rv.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(permissions);
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("MyLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
AssemblyName asm_name = asm.GetName();
rv.LocalReport.AddFullTrustModuleInSandboxAppDomain(new StrongName(new StrongNamePublicKeyBlob(asm_name.GetPublicKeyToken()), asm_name.Name, asm_name.Version));
```

I also needed to set PermissionState.Unrestricted instead of PermissionState.None. In my example I was loading System.Web + System.Drawing and so I only needed up to the `SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain`.